# Getting mean of rows above criteria by group with dplyr

Tags: r, dplyr

I am trying to get the mean for rows above a certain threshold (by group). Unfortunately, my attempts are not leading to valid results.

Data:

```
df <- data.frame(
  id=c(1:10),
  group=c("a", "a", "a", "a", "a", "b", "b", "b", "b", "b"),
  b=rnorm(10,5,1)
)
> df
   id group        b
1   1     a 4.154182
2   2     a 5.958000
3   3     a 3.346686
4   4     a 5.689609
5   5     a 5.003576
6   6     b 5.127969
7   7     b 4.841127
8   8     b 3.268419
9   9     b 3.601477
10 10     b 5.796909
```

Attempts:

```
df %>%
  dplyr::group_by(group) %>%
  summarise(
    mean=mean(b>4)
  )

df %>%
  dplyr::group_by(group) %>%
  summarise(
    mean=mean(which(b>4))
  )
```

Comment: ```df |> 
  summarise(mean = mean(b[b > 4]), .by = group)
```

Comment: @Maël Any advice on how to count number of rows > threshold? So something like summarise(count_rows = sum(b[b>4]))

Comment: `df |>    summarise(count_rows = sum(b > 4), .by = group)`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you need `b[b>4]` before running `mean`

```
df %>%
  summarise(mean = mean(b[b > 4]), .by = group)
```

or you can do `filter` before `summarise`

```
df %>%
  filter(b > 4) %>%
  summarise(mean = mean(b), .by = group)
```

Comment: Any advice on how to count number of rows > threshold? So something like summarise(count_rows = sum(b[b>4]))

Comment: @EML if you want to count, you can use `sum(b>4)`, where `b>4` is just a boolean vector, and the `TRUE`s will be added up as integer `1`s and thus counts.